# Dropdown list item selection in AutoIt

Tags: autoit

How do I get the following script to run my test.pdf file?

```
$Form1 = GUICreate("Form1", 413, 305, 302, 218)
$Combo1 = GUICtrlCreateCombo("Make Selection", 184, 48, 153, 25, BitOR($CBS_DROPDOWN,$CBS_AUTOHSCROLL))
$Combo1 = GUICtrlSetData(-1, "test1|test2|test3")
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
While 1
  $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
           Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
          Exit
        Case $Combo1
          $nMsg2 = GUIGetMsg()
          Switch $nMsg2
        Case "test1"
          ShellExecute("C:\test.pdf")
          EndSwitch
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Comment: You have to use  GUICtrlRead to read the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try it like this:

```
$Form1 = GUICreate("Form1", 413, 305, 302, 218)
$Combo1 = GUICtrlCreateCombo("Make Selection", 184, 48, 153, 25, BitOR($CBS_DROPDOWN,$CBS_AUTOHSCROLL))
GUICtrlSetData(-1, "test1|test2|test3")
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
While 1
  $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
          Exit
        Case $Combo1
          If GUICtrlRead($Combo1) = "Test2" Then
            ShellExecute("C:\test.pdf")
          EndIf
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

This is because GuiCtrlRead gives you back the Value which is selected. And if this Value is "Test2" it makes your shell execute.

The second thing is that you shouldn't do this:

```
$Combo1 = GUICtrlSetData(-1, "test1|test2|test3")
```

Because with this you're overriding the handle which you get from CuiGrtlCreateCombo and you need this handle that the switch case statement works properly.